# Unique constraint validation APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have created a validation for a text field in my application.
The text field is "Location." It has a unique constraint and when you enter an existing location it will give you an ORA- error message. Instead of this, I want to display a field inline error message.
I did the following.

1. Create validation
2. Type: Item=Value
3. Item = :P3_LOCATION, Value = #LOCATION#
4. Error message: Location already exists. Inline with field. Associated item is :P3_LOCATION
5. Server-side Condition
6. When Button Pressed: CREATE, Type = Item is NOT NULL, Item = P3_LOCATION.

This does exactly what I want but when I try to create a new location, it also gives me this error message. What can I do to have it only affect the locations that already exist?

Comment: How are you telling it to create a new location? You want to change your validation's condition to check that too. If it's a Y/N checkbox, you could do something like `:REQUEST = 'CREATE' and :P3_IS_NEW_LOCATION = 'N'`, for example.

Comment: Please add the `create table ...` statement. It's not easy for us to figure out exactly what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you never actually control whether location you're entering right now already exists in the table.

I'd suggest the following:

- create validation on the item
- its type is "PL/SQL Function (returning Error Text)"
- PL/SQL Function Body:

  ```
  declare
    l_loc your_table.location%type;
  begin
    select location
      into l_loc
      from your_table
      where location = :P3_LOCATION;

    return ('Location already exists');
  exception
    when no_data_found then null;
  end;
  ```
- Display position: Inline with field
- Associated item: P3_LOCATION
- When button pressed: CREATE

Comment: Even better would be a "no rows returned" SQL query, leave the coding to the APEX team.